# How to create a hover drop down menu nav bar asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have managed to create a navigation bar that highlights when it is hovered over, but I have not been able to manage to make it a hover drop down list. Is there any way of making this possible? this is the current code that I am using.

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li class="auto-style1"><a runat="server" href="~/" class="auto-style2"><strong><span class="auto-style3"Home Page</span></strong></a></li>
    <li class="auto-style1"><a runat="server" href="~/About" class="auto-style2"><strong><span class="auto-style3"Painting</span></strong></a></li>
    <li class="auto-style1"><a runat="server" href="~/Contact" class="auto-style2"><strong><span class="auto-style3"Drawing</span/strong></a></li>
    <li class="auto-style1"><a runat="server" href="~/" class="auto-style2"><strong><span class="auto-style3"Surfaces</span></strong></a></li>
    <li class="auto-style1"><a runat="server" href="~/About" class="auto-style2"><strong><span class="auto-style3"Easels</span></strong></a></li>
    <li class="auto-style1"><a runat="server" href="~/Contact" class="auto-style2"><strong<span class="auto-style3"Display</span></strong></a></li>
</ul>
```

And finally, this is a screenshot of the product once I run it.

https://gyazo.com/6da0b7c3d170000167003bf0157e64f7

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: @TylerSells Although that link was very useful for many other questions I had, it shows how to make collapsable drop down menus, whereas I only want my menu to drop down when the mouse is over it, not when they click.

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now but I think what you will need to do is add some jQuery or JavaScript to add the class `collapse.in` to the drop down `ul` on the hover event for the associated `li` that performs the collapsing

Comment: They may not be right though.  I'll have to check it out when I get back to a computer

Comment: @TylerSells I'm not too familiar with a lot of those terms since I'm still fairly new when it comes to programming. But take your time, I'll be available all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
To further elaborate on where the below should go, and since we are talking about webforms here, you should open the `Site.Master` page.

**In the Site.Master Page:**
If you have left the default code that Visual Studio builds in, you should see the following lines between the `<Scripts></Scripts>` tags:

```
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" /> 
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
```

This tells us that jQuery and Bootstrap are being imported into the pages.  JQuery is a JavaScript library that makes things a little easier.  Bootstrap is a CSS library that makes it really easy to make things look good by adding a few classes to given elements.

By default, you will also see this in there as well:

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

That should look familiar as it is similar to the markup in your original post.  To add a drop down list, compare the code below that includes a drop down and plug the needed parts into the above code.  Something like this:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 4
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a runat="server" href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                          <li><a runat="server" href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                          <li><a runat="server" href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This *should* get your navbar and dropdown working when you click things.

**Where to put the jQuery:**
So, the best practice for any kind of external scripts, especially large ones, are to load them last, that way the page doesn't have to wait on them to load enough content to make the user happy.  ASP.NET MVC does a much better job than Webforms does in this respect, but we can still try to do things correctly.

On the `Site.Master` page again, go all the way to the bottom.  You're looking for the closing `' tag.  Right before it, you'll need to put this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown").hover(function () {
            //toggle the open class (on/off)
            $(this).toggleClass("open");
        });
    })
</script>
```

So the end result would look like...:

```
... ... ...
... ... ...
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

    </form>
    <script>
        //this line means we won't do anything until the page is ready for it
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $(".dropdown").hover(function () {
                //toggle the open class (on/off)
                $(this).toggleClass("open");
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Before the edit:**

**Note:**  I'm making an assumption that you are using bootstrap and jQuery since this is tagged with asp.net and your original class names appear to be bootstrap syntax as well.

Here is a quick and easy way to accomplish this with bootstrap and jQuery:

**jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/tzv3t12c/9/

**Bootstrap Nav Template:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <!-- This is the li that we want to manually modify on hover.
           Basically, we're going to simulate the bootstrap event that happens
           when the link is clicked.  It doesn't do everything that bootstrap
           does when the link is clicked, but it works easily in a pinch
      -->
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>

      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 4
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Required jQuery:**

```
//find elements with the dropdown class and attach the hover event to it
$(".dropdown").hover(function(){
  //toggle the open class (on/off)
  $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```

**Explanation:**

Essentially, all I'm doing here is simulating the click actions that bootstrap performs when the dropdown link is clicked.  If you use the developer tools in Chrome (or other browsers) by pressing F12, you can watch the HTML while you're interacting with the page.  You'll notice that when the `li` with class `dropdown` is clicked, the open class gets added to it.  There are some other elements that get changed as well and you might want to look into simulating those modifications too since changing the class on the `dropdown` `li` to `dropdown open` does not, even though it activates the transition.

Comment: @TylerSellls so how would I go about changing my code to get it that way?

Comment: Asp.net comes with a default nav bar in the _Layout.cshtml file if you're using mvc.  I'm not sure what it's called on the web forms side.  Asp.net has bootstrap and jQuery built in.  You should be able to modify the above nav snippet to include the links you want  (just replace the `a` elements with your `a` elements).  As far as where to put the jQuery, treat it kind if like JavaScript.  There are a bunch of different places you could put it but it would go between `script` tags and would need to be positioned after the line that imports the jQuery library.

Comment: Hey Tyler, I do not think I am using jQuery as I can't find stuff that is similar to that. my main classes are written with C#, the website is made in html5 and then there is CSS files for the site and bootstrap. I have managed to make the button drop down, but I can not figure out the hover part.

Comment: Are you using MVC or web forms?

Comment: I'm using web forms,

Comment: @Zalgawi I have added further explanation in regards to webforms to my answer,  let me know if you have any more questions