# W3 Schools Nav Bar not working in C# Site.Master

Tags: c#, asp.net, navbar, master-pages

I'm using the code below from the W3 Schools website for a Drop Down Nav Bar which is not working from the Site.Master file within my C# application.

The Nav Bar displays but the drop down menu is not showing.

Not sure where I am going wrong as this sample works perfectly well in the W3 Schools web site when I try it as an example and I have copied like for like in to my site.master within the web application.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

The code is as follows:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-    awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see     https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

                <div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: please check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842549/how-to-create-a-hover-drop-down-menu-nav-bar-asp-net), it may help you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with the help of a friend.

The issue was caused by different versions of Bootstrap being used.

After finding a suitable template at [www.getbootstrap.com](http://www.getbootstrap.com) the issue was resolved.

Thank you for any assistance given.